# Can't create Azure HDInsight(Hadoop)

Tags: azure, hadoop, cloud, azure-hdinsight

I am struggling against creating HDInsight.
After reviewing documents and other posts, I upgraded free-trial to paid subscription and created paid subscription as well.

However, regardless of subscription types(both subscription paid type) I got the following error message.
My understanding is that total used cores is 11 cores(Av2: 3 cores + Ev3: 8 cores) and it is lower than my limitation.

Here is my quotas:
Location: South Central US
Subscription Type: Pay-As-You-Go

- Name: Current, Limit
- Total Regional vCPUs: 0, 96
- Standard Av2 Family vCPUs: 0, 10
- Standard Ev3 Family vCPUs: 0, 10

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this document -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/611894/cluster-terminated-quota-exceeded-expectation-whil.html

I would also suggest try creating HDI in other region

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried it on other region but showing same error

Comment: Pls try creating a ticket after validating the cores as mentioned in the link